# writing Spark ETL job in high performance and object oriented way

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

A conceptual question to achieve high performance in Spark Job.

In ETL job,
I am creating a data frame in Extract phase from a datasource (s3 or database or raw file),

i.e. `df = extract(configs)`

Then In transform phase, i.e. `df_transform = transform(df, configs)`, I am using multiple python methods to transform my dataframe.

i.e. `cleaning(df)`, `setup_different_conditional_edits(df)`, `windowing_function_transformations(df)`, `other_statestical_tranformations(df)`

All the transform functions will return df after applying transformations. (i.e. pandas style)

i.e.

```html
def transform(df, config):
  df = cleaning(df)
  df = setup_different_conditional_edits(df)
  df = windowing_function_transformations(df)
  df = other_statestical_tranformations(df)
  
  return df
```

Now the data frame I am creating in `extract(configs)` is quite huge (~ 10-100 GB). Assuming that I have enough memory and compute resources, is it a good practice to pass huge data frame between two python functions ?
or using UDF is a best bet ?

Also If I am using python class, Is it a good practice to declare spark dataframe as class instance variable ?

i.e. (conceptual)

```html
class Extract(object):
    def __init__(configs):
        """ declaring configs as instance variable """
        self.configs = configs
    
    def run(self):
        """ All Extraction Methods """

        return df

class Transform(object):
    def __init__(df):
        """ passing df as instance variable """
        self.df = df
    
    def run(self):
        """ All Transformation Methods """
        self.df = cleaning()
        self.df = setup_different_conditional_edits()
        self.df = windowing_function_transformations()
        self.df = other_statestical_tranformations()
        
        return self.df

class Load(object):
    def __init__(df):
        """ passing df as instance variable """
        self.df = df
    
    def run():
        """ Logic for loading transformed df """

        return True
```